# How to fix readJavaFormatString error?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, actionlistener, jtogglebutton

I have to use netbeans GUI builder for this assignment, so I only included the code that I created. I did not include any of the pre-generated stuff.
My main issue is that I don't know why my code keeps generating error messages like: (I'm not expecting anyone to read every error, this is just to get a general idea)

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at JL_5GUIbuilder.jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(JL_5GUIbuilder.java:201)
at JL_5GUIbuilder.access$400(JL_5GUIbuilder.java:15)
at JL_5GUIbuilder$5.actionPerformed(JL_5GUIbuilder.java:85)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Please help me fix the code below. I don't know why it's wrong, but it is and I'd really appreciate any advice. So far I haven't found any answers that are really similar to my problem on stack overflow. I also haven't found any answers that I understand.

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                               
//calculate revenue
double percent = .2;

//converting adult price to a decimal number
float adultPrice = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.toString());

//convert number of adult tickets sold to int
int numA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.toString());

//converting child ticket price to a decimal number
float childPrice = Float.parseFloat(jTextField3.toString());

//converting to an int
int numC = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.toString());

//parsing string to a double and multiplying by the cost of an adult ticket to get gross for adult tickets
float grossA = adultPrice * numA;

//getting net amount by taking out movie company cut of 20% from gross
float netA = (float) (grossA * percent);

//calculating gross by parsing strings to doubles and then multiplying
float grossC = childPrice * numC;

//calculating net amount for children tickets sold
float netC = (float) (grossC * percent);

//calculating total gorss for all tickets sold
float totalGross = grossC + grossA;

//calculating total net amount
float totalNet = netA + netC;

textArea1.setText("Total gross adult revenue:" + String.valueOf(grossA) +"\n"+"Total net adult revenue : " + String.valueOf(netA) + "\n" +"Total gross child revenue:" +String.valueOf(grossC) + "\n" + "Total net child revenue : " + String.valueOf(netC) + "\n" +"Total gross revenue of sales : " + String.valueOf(totalGross) + "\n " +"Total net revenue of sales: " + String.valueOf(totalNet));
}
```

Comment: What line is the error pointing to? (there are no line numbers in your code)

Comment: What are the strings in the text fields?

Comment: What is jTextField1 ? shouldn't it be jTextField1.getText()?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change

```
jTextField1.toString()
```

To

```
jTextField1.getText()
```

and the same issue to `jTextField2` , `jTextField3` , `jTextField4`